# {"error":{"message":"Services require JSON-RPC","code":0,"origin":2},"id":null}

Tags: javascript, jquery, json-rpc

Iam new to  json RPC. when I type the url of the  service that provides the methods for invoking  in browser I get the folowing message :

> {"error":{"message":"Services require JSON-RPC","code":0,"origin":2},"id":null}

Can anyone explain to me what is this message and whay i am getting it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON RPC expects the client to send parameters to the server using an HTTP POST command with the procedure parameters in the post data. When you type a URL into the browser it sends an HTTP GET command, which doesn't send any parameters.

RPC is intended for use by application programs, not directly by end users. See http://json-rpc.org/ for more details about it.